# Parse Array relation column in PFUser current User

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Is it possible to include Parse array relation column in `[PFUser currentUser]` ?

It would be best if this can be done once.

Comment: What is `array relation column`? Arrays and relations are different things. What have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I have one array column in User and I need to include that array so it's populated, right now i just have array of pointers. I'm confused how I can include it on current user.

Comment: You mean include the data it contains in the response when you query for the `User`? Really not clear what you're trying to do...

Comment: I want to know is there way to have "include" options for array columns on currentUser ? In my case I have _user[@"sports"]  field and this is array of pointers. How i can get data from @sports field ... right now I just have objectID

Comment: Yes, use the `include` flag for that key in the query